# android CamcorderProfile.hasProfile NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-camera

I am getting a runtime NoSuchMethodError when trying to use CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(xyz).
In my app's manifest the correct API are specified

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

and this is the block I would like to use

```
CamcorderProfile cf = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P)) {
   cf = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
} else if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_CIF)) {
    cf = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_CIF);
} else if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA)) {
   cf = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA);
}
```

I don't get any errors in Eclipse when writing / building, even code completion works fine. 
**EDIT** at this point I run the code on a few devices (Galaxy, Incredible and Desire).

The stacktrace error is

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12499): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12499): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Android.media.CamcorderProfile.hasProfile
```

Any hint why this happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Bruno was right, it seems like it was a problem of API level.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the AVD? You put the support needed for media and camera in the AVD?

Try to test you application in a real device.

Comment: Hey Bruno, thanks for your reply and sorry for not mentioning it in the issue. I am testing it on a few phones (Samsung Galaxy, HTC Desire and Incredible).

Comment: QUALITY_QVGA is from API level 15, maybe this is the problem: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#QUALITY_QVGA